# Isomorphic react, unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

I rebuilt my application to an isomorphic approach.
Everything worked fine on my local enviroment (node version local and online is the same)
But unfortunately after uploading the files to my webserver I get the following error message:

```
SyntaxError: .../index.js: Unexpected token (74:62)
  72 |                       friends: friends
  73 |                     }
> 74 |                     var reactString = ReactDOM.renderToString(<IndexApp {...props}/>)
                                                                     ^
```

This directly points to the < in `<IndexApp..`

My requirement list looks as following:

```
var React = require('react')
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom/server')

var IndexApp = require('../public/js/build/components/IndexApp').default
var PostApp = require('../public/js/build/components/PostApp').default
```

I can't find any proper solution to that. I gladly appreciate any hints.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for Javascript with JSX to work in the browser, it has to be transpiled first.  You can do that within the page by including Babel and changing the script type to 'text/babel'. First, put this in the `<head>` of the page:

```
<script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
```

And then wrap your jsx-containing Javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/babel">
 ... code goes here ...
</script>
```

Comment: Oh i forgot about babel... :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to transpile the jsx to javascript.  You can do that with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/), something like

`babel my-file.js --presets react -o output.js`

Comment: totally forgot about it :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two options here :
1)For dev environment you can wrap jsx code like this

```
<script type="text/babel" src="yourfile"/>
```

and also include `browser.min.js`
This will be transpiled in your browser.

2)For prod environment you need to transpile it first .You can do this on your local machine  using babel

```
babel --presets es2015,react --minified financialFeed.js -o ./compiled/compiled.js
```

or you can do it online by going to

```
https://babeljs.io/repl/
```

Comment: totally forgot about babel